# Replacing key value in dict B with dict A values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am a bit puzzled by this piece of code: here it is

```
def newval(A, B):
    for key in A:
        if key in B:
            B[key][1] = A[key][0]
            return B
```

This will not run at all in my program for some reason.
Basically I want it to go through dict A, loop through and find the same key in dict B, and then replace dict B key value with the A one.

Comment: What does "will not run at all" mean? What is the type of values in the dicts? What if they are more than on matching keys? Do you want to replace all of the corresponding values?

Comment: Your function returns after the first `key in B` is `True`. Is that the correct behaviour?

Comment: It doesn't even go through the function, that's what I mean. @YS-L

Answer (score 1):

You can try by this code:

```
 def newval(A, B):
    print A
    print B
    for key in A:
       print key
       if key in B:
           print key
           B[key]=A[key]
            print B
       return B


A = {'asd':4, 'ad':32}
B = {'asd':5, 'asd':234}
b=newval(A,B)
print b
```

output:

```
{'asd': 4}
{'asd': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
>>> A = {'foo':2, 'bar':3}
>>> B = {'foo':5, 'baram':3}
>>> for key in A:
    if key in B:
        B[key]=A[key]


>>> A
{'bar': 3, 'foo': 2}
>>> B
{'baram': 3, 'foo': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def newval(A, B):
    for key in A:
        if key in B:
            B[key] = A[key]
    return B
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing at all worked, so I suspected there was something wrong with the file being read. This was indeed correct, dict B's keys had single quotes in them which A didn't, and couldn't compare them at all, since none of them matched.

Original code works just fine:

```
def newval(A, B):
for key in A:
    if key in B:
        B[key][1] = A[key][0]
        return B
```